# Copy-Paste above row's Range if a specific range is empty and another is not

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019

I have a table in an active worksheet.

I am trying to:

1. Scan Columns(A:M) of Row 6 to see if all cells are empty
2. If yes, then scan Columns (N:R) of Row 6 to see if all cells are empty
3. If 2. is false, then copy above row's Columns (A:I) in Row 6
4. Repeat 1-3 but on Row 7

This process should repeat until the rows of the table end.

I would like to incorporate `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name` or something similar to duplicate the sheet without having to tweak the code.

How I can make this as efficient and as risk free as possible? My code works but it's really too much.

```vb
Sub CopyPasteRow()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim a As Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    a = 0
    For x = 6 To lr
        For y = 1 To 13
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, y)) Then
                a = a + 1
            End If
        Next y
        If a = 0 Then
            For y = 14 To 18
                If Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, y)) Then
                    a = a + 1
                End If
            Next y
        Else
            a = 0
        End If
        If a <> 0 Then
                For y = 1 To 13
                    Cells(x, y).Value = Cells(x - 1, y).Value
                Next y
        End If
    a = 0
    Next x
End Sub
```

This is the final code based on @CHill60 code. It got me 99% where I wanted.

```vb
Sub CopyPasteRow()
Dim lr As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim r As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 6 To lr
    'check columns A to M for this row are empty
        Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & CStr(x) & ":M" & CStr(x))
    
    'check columns N to R for this row are empty
        Set r2 = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & CStr(x) & ":R" & CStr(x))
    
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r) = 0 And WorksheetFunction.CountA(r2) <> 0 Then
        'copy the data into columns A to M
        Set r3 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & CStr(x) & ":I" & CStr(x))
        r3.Value = r3.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking at individual cells, look at Ranges instead. Consider this snippet of code

```
Sub demo()
    Dim x As Long
    
    For x = 6 To 8
    
        Dim r As Range
        Set r = Sheets(1).Range("A" & CStr(x) & ":M" & CStr(x))
        Debug.Print r.Address, MyIsEmpty(r)
   
    Next x
End Sub
```

I have a function for checking for empty ranges

```
Public Function MyIsEmpty(rng As Range) As Boolean
    MyIsEmpty = WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0
End Function
```

I use this because the cell might "look" empty, but actually contain a formula.

Note I've explicitly said which sheet I want the Cells from - users have a habit of clicking places other than where you think they should be! :laugh:

Edit after OP comment:

E.g. your function might look like this

```
Sub CopyPasteRow()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim r As Range, r2 As Range
    
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For x = 6 To lr
        
        a = 0
    
        'check columns A to M for this row are empty
        Set r = Sheets(1).Range("A" & CStr(x) & ":M" & CStr(x))
        If Not MyIsEmpty(r) Then
            a = a + 1
        End If
        
        If a = 0 Then
            'check columns N to R for this row are empty
            Set r2 = Sheets(1).Range("N" & CStr(x) & ":R" & CStr(x))
            If Not MyIsEmpty(r2) Then
                a = a + 1
            End If
        Else
            a = 0
        End If
        
        If a <> 0 Then
            'copy the data into columns A to M
            'You might have to adjust the ranges here
            r.Value = r2.Value
        End If
    
    Next x

End Sub
```

where you have a source range and a target range - you appear to be putting the values in the previous row so my value of `r` is probably wrong in this example - you could use `r.Offset(-1,0).Value = r2.Value`
I'm also not sure what you are trying to do with the variable `a` If that is meant to be a "flag" then consider using a Boolean instead - it only has the values True or False

Comment: Thank you for your insight man. I am kinda getting where you going with it, but I am a bit confused. Could you possibly explain a little bit more on how I could implement it for my test case?

Comment: Thank you so much man! Really appreciate taking the time helping out :)